# the best way to store dates for a huge data

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a data logger that stores the reading of a sensor every second as in the table bellow:

```
16:21:53    10.51   19.47   16.89   16.4
16:21:53    4.44    8.03    6.86    6.33
16:21:53    1.99    2.18    2.42    1.28
16:21:54    1.41    0.72    2.39    1.28
16:21:54    1.06    1.85    2.99    2.08
16:21:54    1.04    2.27    3.27    2.29
16:21:56    1       2.46    3.07    2.34
16:21:56    1.13    2.26    3.24    2.07
16:21:56    0.93    2.05    2.84    1.81
16:21:57    0.99    1.88    2.61    1.63
16:21:57    0.85    1.61    2.44    1.35
16:21:57    0.7     1.4     2.26    1.14
16:21:58    0.63    1.27    2.34    0.99
```

its inconvenient to store the date for all these rows as it will consume a lot of space in the memory, what is the best way to store a single value of date for all these rows?  my point is, instead of having a new column called datas and insert 
25/2/2015 for the row at 16:21:53 and another date for the row at 16:21:54 and so on , I want to use 25/2/2015 for 1 time for all the rows or any other efficient way to do this as general database design.

Comment: usually such data stored in different files or tables, ie new file for each day or hour/minute

Comment: @Lashane nooooo! That is a terrible idea.

Comment: @SalmanA yeah, that terrible idea is used in many many logging frameworks

Comment: What you're getting at really is creating a foreign key in this table pointing at a calendar table. You still need to define the foreign key on each row.

Comment: @sabir: are you running out of disk space or something?

Comment: @Lashane I think the files is a good idea if I just want to store these values in text files or SCV files and review and process them manually but is it effective if I want to use SQL database for example ? could you suggest me some logging frameworks so I get an idea about how they do this kind of things?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid actually this is the first idea came into my mind but still I think that its efficient

Comment: @Salman A , I am not, but I just want to make sure that I am implementing the most efficient way of doing this as I will be storing data for years and its really huge

Comment: @SabirMoglad log4j can split into multiple files

Comment: Adding complexity is not making it more efficient. I think you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server a `datetime` takes 8 bytes but if you don't plan to use your data logger after 2079 you could use `smalldatetime` which takes only 4 bytes.

This is better than trying to store dates and times with integers which usually results in using more than 4 bytes plus headaches plus CPU time from conversions. I don't know about other **dbms**s but there should be similar options.

**Edit:**

I just checked for MySql and it looks like you can use `timestamp` which can hold both date and time and it's also stored on 4 bytes.

Read here about storage requirements and limitations:
[MySql DateTime Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time)
[MySql date and time data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Another example:

In Oracle 11G the recommended data type for you is `date`. Despite the fact that it's the smallest type that can store your data it still requires 7 bytes (`timestamp` requires 12 bytes but can store fractional seconds).
[Oracle Datetime data types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21901_01/timesten.1122/e21642/types.htm#TTSQL151)

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't think of any SQL dbms that uses *more* than 8 bytes for a timestamp. I don't think there are many (any?) besides SQL Server that support a 4-byte timestamp, but I'm pretty sure the OP's better off with actual timestamps, regardless of their length.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of techniques you can use and a variety of packaged solutions dealing with time-series sensor data. Look into Process Historian and SCADA solutions, streaming databases and complex event processing (CEP) software. There is also a quantity of published scientific and data management theory material on these topics if you want to understand some techniques you can implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "standard" way to do such.  Furthermore, it is technically impossible since database table rows have no inherent "order".  Your scheme would depend on an order to reconstruct the date+time.

Is it practical to "summarize", as you insert, the data from each 1-minute period (max, min, avg, whatever) and store that in a much shorter (1/60 the rows), but slightly wider (more columns) table?

Or, keep the details of the last hour's sensor readings, but after that summarize as above?

Comment: thanks @Rick James for the reply, 
actually its a data logger for the RMS current profile for washing machines and every value is needed so i can't represent the data using single value as average or whatever